# range-based 'for' expression of type ... has incomplete type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile some old code. I am sure it worked then. Now I've got the folloing error:
Led7x4.cpp: 74:23: error: range-based 'for' expression of type 'Led7Font []' has incomplete type

**Here is my code:**

```
// font_7seg.cpp
Led7Font LED7_FONT[]{
    {'0', 0b1111110}
};


// font_7seg.h
class Led7Font
{
public:
    char c;
    byte b;
};

extern Led7Font LED7_FONT[];


// later in the coder:
for (Led7Font font : LED7_FONT) // here I’ve got error ‘error: range-based 'for' expression of type 'Led7Font []' has incomplete type’
{
}
```

Comment: Is `byte` defined as a type somewhere?

Comment: @AdrianMole It is, like typedef uint8_t byte;